# GoImports kills html syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, go, vim-plugin

In the following go code:

```
var rootTemplate = template.Must(template.New("root").Parse(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 /SNIP/
</html>
`))
```

I am able to make the html part highlighted as html with this function:

```
function! GoHtml()
    if !empty(b:current_syntax)
        unlet b:current_syntax
    endif
    syn include @html syntax/html.vim
    syntax region htmlCode start=+<!DOCTYPE+ keepend end=+</html>+ contains=@html containedIn=goRawString contained
endfunction
autocmd BufEnter *.go call GoHtml()
```

However after I saved the document, the html syntax highlighting disappears when calling GoImports: `let g:go_fmt_command = "GoImports"`

Is there a way to keep embeeded html highlighted?

Comment: The more I read about these problems with `goimports`, the more I'm glad I stuck to only use `gofmt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I nailed it to this:

```
function! GoHtml()
    GoFmt
    if !empty(b:current_syntax)
            unlet b:current_syntax
    endif
    syn include @html syntax/html.vim
    syntax region htmlCode start=+<!DOCTYPE+ keepend end=+</html>+ contains=@html containedin=goRawString contained
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter *.go call GoHtml()
autocmd BufWrite *.go call GoHtml()

execute pathogen#infect()

" don't save automatically, let us handle this
let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0

" for golang: automatically run GoImports
let g:go_fmt_command = "GoImports"
```

That way I can have mixed go and html code colored the way I want.